# jQuery for-loop with :eq / get - compress breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm having problem compressing a breadcrumb. If the breadcrumbs gets to many elemnents, and spans over more than one line I want some of the start elements to get compressed ("...").

**ex 1**

```
var height = $('#breadcrumbsContainer > span').height();
var length = $('#breadcrumbsContainer > span span').length;

while (height > 17) {

 for (var j = 1; j < length; j++) {
    if ($('#breadcrumbsContainer > span').get(j).find('a').text() != "...") {
        if ($('#breadcrumbsContainer > span').get(j).find('a').text("..."));
    }
    j++;
 }
};
```

**ex 2**

```
var height = $('#breadcrumbsContainer > span').height();
var length = $('#breadcrumbsContainer > span span').length;

while (height > 17) {

for (var j = 1; j < length; j++) {
    if ($('#breadcrumbsContainer > span:eq(j) a').text() != "...") {
        if ($('#breadcrumbsContainer > span:eq(j) a').text("..."));
    }
    j++;
}
```

};

Everything works greate without using ".get(j)" or :eq(j) inside the for loop. Everytime I run the code it seems like it takes the first element, and not the second one for (j = **1**). (I don't want to compress the root node)

jsFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/TPqfK/3/

Comment: Do you have a working example of the problem that you can share please?

Comment: @andyb http://jsfiddle.net/TPqfK/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative solution:** My original answer is still below but I was thinking about how to do this in a different way so created a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZByff/) of the following code, where changing `BREADCRUMBS_MAX_WIDTH` for a larger or smaller value will allow for more or less *ellipsis-izing* and changing `.last()` to `.first()` will make the higher level breadcrumbs be *ellipsis-ized* first :-)

JavaScript (requires jQuery)

```
var BREADCRUMBS_MAX_WIDTH = 700;

function crumbsWidth() {
  var width = 0;
  $('#breadcrumbs li').each(function() {
    width += $(this).outerWidth();
  });
  return width;
}

while (crumbsWidth() >= BREADCRUMBS_MAX_WIDTH && $('#breadcrumbs li').length - 2 !== $('#breadcrumbs li.ellipsis').length) {
  $('#breadcrumbs li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(.ellipsis)').last().addClass('ellipsis');
}
```

CSS

```
#breadcrumbs {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size:0;
}
#breadcrumbs li {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:16px;
  padding-left:4px;
}
#breadcrumbs li:not(:first-child):before {
  content:'\002192  ';
}
.ellipsis {
  width:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  <li>sit amet, consectetur</li>
  <li>adipisicing elit, sed</li>
  <li>do eiusmod tempor</li>
  <li>incididunt ut labore</li>
  <li>et dolore magna aliqua</li>
  <li>Ut enim ad minim</li>
</ul>
```

**Original answer:**

Initially I had some problems running the code before the fiddle was added which I'll cover first.

The `while (height > 17)` control flow statement can cause an infinite loop which may result in 100% CPU and could crash a browser or tab. I see in the fiddle that you have provided a way to break out of the loop though, but the code in the question should really fully describe the problem.

There is a selector problem with `$('#breadcrumbsContainer > span')` in that you are using the CSS Child combinator `>` which only returns direct children and not all descendants. With this markup in your fiddle:

```
  <div id="breadcrumbsContainer">
    <span id="ctl00_breadcrumb">
      <span><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Min startside</a></span>
      <span></span>
      <span><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">dfa as dfdsa dsa fdsfas</a></span>
      <span></span>
      <span><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">a fdsa fsd adsfdsasad fdsa</a></span>
      <span></span>
      <span><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">test aff for log og opr sds</a></span>
      <span></span>
      <span><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">TESTs sds</a></span>
      <span></span>
      <span>anders er awesome</span>
    </span>
  </div>​
```

the selector is finding the `<span id="ctl00_breadcrumb">` and not the breadcrumb spans. So you might need to correct that to be `$('#breadcrumbsContainer span span')`

That will still not fix the problem because using `$('#breadcrumbsContainer span span').get(j)` will cause a JavaScript error as the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a DOM element and not a jQuery wrapped object so you cannot call `.find()` on it.

The second example using [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) will also not work because the `j` variable is part of the selector string, rather than a variable value and will not cause an error in jQuery. So,

```
$('#breadcrumbsContainer > span:eq(j) a')
```

should be

```
$('#breadcrumbsContainer > span:eq(' + j + ') a')
```

However with all these changes, the resultant selector will still not work due to the way in which `:eq()` operates. From the documentation

> :eq filters the set of elements that have matched the expressions that precede them

so `$('#breadcrumbsContainer span span')` will select all the breadcrumbs and spacer elements and then apply the filter. So `:eq(0)` will be the first breadcrumb and `:eq(1)` will be the first *spacer span*.

So taking all of these changes, we end up with:

```
for (var j = 2; j < length; j++) { // <--- starts at 2 (do not change first breadcrumb)
    if ($('#breadcrumbsContainer span span:eq(' + j + ') a').text() != "...") {
       if ($('#breadcrumbsContainer span span:eq(' + j + ') a').text("..."));
    }
    j++;
}
```

**Note:** This above loop will work but it is not very efficient for the following reasons:

1. Empty `<span>` elements to pad the breadcrumbs can be removed in favour of spacing each breadcrumb with CSS
2. Use more semantic markup to describe the data for example `<ul><li></li></ul>` instead
3. The `:eq()` selector is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method <sup>[**[docs]**](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)</sup>
4. Might be simpler to use the [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow) CSS property `text-overflow:ellipsis` and change the *width* of each breadcrumb rather than changing the `<a>` text.

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative solution based off of the comments at the end of the original answer